# Restore Windows files permissions

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

I removed some required permissions on my C drive by mistake and now web browsers and Outlook are not working. How can I restore these permissions (I don't know how many and which one has been removed).

Comment: Tried icacls but most files failed with access denied.

Comment: I've changed the owner and when I try to set the permission for all folders I still get an access denied. The applications must be opened as administrator to work.

Comment: Did you open the [command prompt as an administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes. [Padding for stackoverflow]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to add several permissions manually with the help of Process Monitor.
It's not the best solution, but I can't spend my time on this.